# Obter lista de arquivos alterados no diretório de trabalho (working directory)

Tags: git

Quando se executa o comando `git diff` no terminal é aberta uma janela que apresenta o conteúdo dos arquivos com suas alterações. A partir daí posso saber quais arquivos foram alterados. O problema desse método é que para saber quais ou quantos arquivos foram alterados preciso ir até o fim do último arquivo apresentado.

Preciso de um recurso mais simples. Um recurso que mostre somente o nome dos arquivos alterados.

Qual o **comando** usado para listar os arquivos que foram alterados, mas não foram comitados?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu tenho a impressão que você quer apenas os arquivos modificados. Sem os arquivos "untracked" ou "staged". Nesse caso utilize

```
git ls-files --modified
```

ou

```
git ls-files -m
```

obs: os arquivos no índice não foram comitados ainda. Mas não ficou claro se você quer listar esses arquivos. Como o seu exemplo é a saída do `git diff` estou supondo que não.

Answer (score 4):

O comando para ver os arquivos alterados que não foram comitados é o `git status`, conforme exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No link abaixo, você encontra maiores informações sobre gravar alterações no repositório e verificar status dos seus arquivos:

[Git Essencial - Gravando Alterações no Repositório](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Essencial-Gravando-Altera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-Reposit%C3%B3rio)

Answer (score 0):

O comando para mostrar os estado do repositório listando todos os arquivos alterados e novos arquivos (*untracked files*) é:

`git status`

Answer (score 0):

Para saber os arquivos da branch que ainda não estão na master, você pode utilizar este comando:

```
git diff --name-only master
```

Isto é útil para saber quais arquivos devem ir para a produção, por exemplo.